# Expresion regular para validar un campo que tenga letras y numeros con un minimo de caracteres js

Tags: javascript, regex

tengo una expresion regular que supuestamente valida que la cadena de texto tenga numeros y letras con un minimo de 8 caracteres, el problema surge es que solo valida la longitud y no valida que tenga numeros y letras, que me hace falta para que funcione? `let expr = /[A-Za-z0-9!?-]{8,12}/;`

Answer (score 2):

```
\A(?=[A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,12}\Z
```

Primero, con la la cláusula (?=...) se verifica que haya letras Y dígitos. Luego se valida que sean entre 8 y 12 letras o dígitos.
Falla si todos los caracteres son dígitos y falla si todos son letras.

Ver la prueba aquí: https://regex101.com/r/8OczSH/1